# i want to convert a color image to grayscale and save it in a file..

Tags: java

my below code saves the image..but its not black and white... its either black or white..
please help with it..if there is any error..help me out :(
and friends please try to help me with this same code itself.. i wont be understanding any other codes currently.. HELP...!!! (this code is a part of my whole code for implementing backpropagation algorithm)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class PrintImageARGBPixels
{

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {   
        //extracting RGB values of each pixel of an image.

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new 
            File("C:\\Users\\ark\\Desktop\\project_doc\\logo_1004.jpg"));
        int total_pixels=1;
        float sum=0;
        ArrayList <Color> arr = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList <Float> grey_f = new ArrayList<Float>();
        System.out.println("Image Dimension: Height-" + h + ", Width-"+ w);
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        total_pixels=(h * w);
        for(x=0;x<w;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<h;y++)
            {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                Color c = new Color(rgb);
                arr.add(c);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<total_pixels;i++)
        {
            sum=(arr.get(i).getRed()+arr.get(i).getGreen()+arr.get(i).getBlue())/(3*255);
            grey_f.add(sum);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<total_pixels;i++)
        {
            Color co=new Color(grey_f.get(i),grey_f.get(i),grey_f.get(i));
            int rgb_1=co.getRGB();
            for(x=0;x<w;x++)
            {
                for(y=0;y<h;y++)
                {
                    image.setRGB(x,y,rgb_1);
                }
            }
        }
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new 
            File("C:\\Users\\ark\\Desktop\\project_doc\\multi_gray.png"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every RGB value you get, do

```
Color c = new Color(rgb);

int gr = (c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c.getBlue())/3;

Color greyScale = new Color(gr, gr, gr);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: its giving an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter o
utside of expected range: Red Green Blue"

Comment: @ark Try printing the value of `gr`

Comment: its giving 255 each... :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with `sum=arr.get(i).getRed()+arr.get(i).getGreen()+arr.get(i).getBlue())/(3*255);` as that returns an `int` of either 0 or 1. You actually only need to divide by `3` to get a value in the range of [0,255].